# Update Swing GUI from other thread

Tags: java, swing, sockets, event-dispatch-thread

I have two classes, one of them is my thread in which I read outputs from a device through TCP/IP:

```
public static controlPanel cp = new controlPanel();
void startListenForTCP (final String ipaddress){  
Thread TCPListenerThread;
TCPListenerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
       @Override  
       public void run() {    
           Boolean run = true;
           String serverMessage = null;
           InetAddress serverAddr = null;
             BufferedWriter out = null;
             try
                 (Socket clientSocket = new Socket(ipaddress, 7420)) {
                  cp.updateGUI("Connection initiated... waiting for outputs!"+"\n");
                 char[] buffer = new char[2];
                 int charsRead = 0;
                 out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
                 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                 while ((charsRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
                 {
                     String message = new String(buffer).substring(0, charsRead);
                     switch (message) {
                         case "o,":
                             cp.updateGUI("Čekanje da loptica prođe RFID čitač!");
                             break;
                         case "y,":
                             cp.updateGUI("Hardverski problem!");
                             break;
                         case "Y,":
                             cp.updateGUI("Loptica nije izažla, hardverski problem!");
                             break;
                         case "I,":
                             cp.updateGUI("Uređaj u stanju mirovanja!!");
                             break;
                         default:
                             String m = message;
                             m = m.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
                             try{
                                 int i = Integer.parseInt(m);
                                 System.out.println("Is int: "+i);


                                 int izasao=Integer.parseInt(m);

                                 if (redni>34){
                                     redni=0;
                                 }
                                 if (izasao>0 && izasao<49){
                                     redni =redni+1;
                                     m=m;
                                     ur.updateResults(redni, m);
                                     bs.testAuto(m, redni);
                                     System.out.println(m+ "\n");
                                 }
                             } catch(NumberFormatException e){
                             }                                  break;
                     }

                 }}
             catch(UnknownHostException e) {

                 System.out.println("Unknown host..."+"\n");
             } catch(IOException e) {
                 System.out.println("IO Error..."+"\n");
             }
       }

   });
TCPListenerThread.start();
```

}

The other one is swing form in which i want to set jLabel text from the class above:

```
Public class controlPanel extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public static gameControler gc = new gameControler();
 public controlPanel() {
    initComponents();
}
       public void updateGUI(final String text) {
   if (!SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      updateGUI(text);
   }
 });
   }jLabel5.setText(text);
     System.out.println(text);
 }
```

The message gets printed out in console but i can't set it's value to jLabel.

I need a quick way to achieve this, so any workarounds will be most helpfull.

Thank you,

Comment: you probably need to use the `SwingWorker` class instead of a normal thread.

Comment: Can you please show me on this example how to achieve this?

Comment: Here you go: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

Answer (score 3):

Your code only updates the GUI if current thread is **not** the EDT:

```
if (!SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
    // you call SwingUtilities.invokeLater();
}
```

The GUI update should also happen if the current thread happens to be the EDT. So you should change it to somehting like this:

```
if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread())
    jLabel5.setText(text);
else
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            jLabel5.setText(text);
        }
    });
```

Note that `invokeLater()` is not executed immediately but asynchronously some time *later*. If you need the update to happen before it returns, use [`SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait-java.lang.Runnable-).

Also note that you may consider using the [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) class to perform lengthy GUI-interaction tasks in a background thread.

### Making it utility method

If you have to do this many times, it is profitable to make a utilitiy method for this:

```
public void callFromEdt(Runnable task) {
    if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread())
        task.run();
    else
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(task); // You might want to consider
                                          // using invokeAndWait() instead
}
```

Comment: I get this error:
`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:285)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.isDispatchThreadImpl(EventQueue.java:1035)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.isDispatchThread(EventQueue.java:1030)
 at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread(SwingUtilities.java:1361)
 at tryout.controlPanel.updateGUI(controlPanel.java:305)
 at tryout.controlPanel.updateGUI(controlPanel.java:306)
 at tryout.controlPanel.updateGUI(controlPanel.java:306)`

Line 306 is    `updateGUI(text);`

Comment: I didn't realize you called the same method `updateGUI()` from itself. I updated the code.

Comment: Still nothing, nothing happens if i call method updateGUI from thread but when i call it from form (on button click) and pass some text everything is printed out in jlabel. But with thread it does not work

Comment: Then try it with `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()` insteand of `invokeLater()`. Are you blocking the EDT btw?

Comment: Still nothing even with invokeAndWait().7
I realy don't get it, that's the whole code of my application in the question above.